# Snowflake SQL procedure with dynamic query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following SQL procedure in Snowflake, where I would like to dynamic add addiational lines to my select_statement bases on the variable c_input (which can have the value e.g. A,B,C) so the select_statement would then contains 3 rows where the comma sep. values are used.

My procedure look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dynamic_query_example(c_input VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
  select_statement VARCHAR;
  res RESULTSET;
BEGIN
  select_statement := 'create or replace temporary table TEST_TBL as 
                       SELECT * 
                       FROM c_data 
                       WHERE c_name IN (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(''' || c_input || ''', '','')))';
  res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :select_statement);
  RETURN 'OK';
END;
```

So select_statement end some like this (One row per item in input var):

```
select_statement := 'create or replace temporary table TEST_TBL as 
                       SELECT *,
                              A,
                              B,
                              C 
                       FROM c_data 
                       WHERE c_name IN (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(''' || c_input || ''', '','')))';
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to pass arguments as array(plus there is no need for dynamic SQL):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dynamic_query_example(c_input ARRAY)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
BEGIN
  create or replace temporary table TEST_TBL as 
  SELECT * 
  FROM c_data 
  WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c_name::VARIANT, :c_input);

  RETURN 'OK';
END;
```

Invocation:

```
CALL dynamic_query_example(['A','B','C']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did declare a cursor:

```
c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT VALUE as Q FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(?, ','));
```

And open the cursor with the input:

```
open c1 using (:cstic);
```

Then loop to generate the addtition to the query:

```
FOR record_y IN c1 DO
query_cstic := query_cstic || 'CASE when "''' || record_y.Q ||'''" = '''' 
THEN NULL ELSE "''' || record_y.Q ||'''" end '|| record_y.Q ||' ,' ;
END FOR;
query_cstic := LEFT(query_cstic, LENGTH(query_cstic) - 1);
close c1;
```

And then add query_cstic to the query and the input are used.